# If a time falls between two times - update value to new time

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure minutes that children are in an after school program to do billing.  The teachers clock them in anytime between 3:15pm and 3:45pm but I want to start billing at 3:30

Data is formatted this way incoming:

```
Child 1:  3:27:00 PM   4:39:00 PM
Child 2:  3:34:00 PM   5:21:00 PM
Child 3:  3:37:00 PM   4:45:00 PM
```

So I'd want to update all those in times to 3:30:00 PM so I can figure the hours/minutes that they were in after care to charge them .10/minute.  Can I do that in all one formula or do I need to break it down into a few different steps?

Any help is super appreciated!  Thanks in advance!  :-)

Comment: So you want to round the incoming time to the nearest 30 minutes?

Comment: If you are billing after 3:30 then you can essentially ignore the second column, treating them all as 3:30. Then you find the difference from 3:30.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to round to the nearest 30 minute interval and return the amount:

```
=(C1-MROUND(B1,TIME(0,30,0)))*0.1*60*24
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I think you want to do, at least to get you started.

Set up your data like this:

```
|   |     A    |      B      |      C     |          D         |
|---|:--------:|:-----------:|:----------:|:------------------:|
| 1 |          | Start Time: | 3:30 PM    |                    |
| 2 |          | Drop Off    | Pick Up    | Minutes After 3:30 |
| 3 | Child 1: | 3:27:00 PM  | 4:39:00 PM | 69                 |
| 4 | Child 2: |  3:34:00 PM | 5:21:00 PM | 107                |
| 5 | Child 3: |  3:37:00 PM | 4:45:00 PM | 68                 |
```

So now in cell `D3`, use this formula:

```
=IF(B3<$C$1,(C3-$C$1)*1440, (C3-B3)*1440)
```

What this does is checks to see if your drop off time (in `B3`) is before or after the start time (3:30pm in cell `C1`). Then it will subtract the two times to get a decimal value based on a 24 hour clock, so you multiply the result by 1,440 minutes to get the number of minutes the child has been there.

Comment: Not sure where you got `<`. `So I'd want to update all those in times to 3:30:00 PM` to me, means that all the times between 3:15 and 3:45 go to 3:30 not just those less than.

Comment: Well true, it was my own thinking that if I was paying ten cents per minute and I was seven minutes late, I wouldn't necessarily want to pay for those seven minutes. But that's a judgement call on my part, and wasn't exactly in the OP's question. Take your upvote! ;)

Comment: Yea... I want to say times between 3:15 and 3:45 because we also have a before care that times will come in saying 7:30am and I don't want to change those.

Comment: So if the time is between 3:15 and 3:45, I want to change them and start billing at 3:30.  If it's outside those times, I want to leave them alone.